# %HOMEDRIVE% is not giving the expected output

Tags: windows, batch-file

When i run the below batch script

```
@echo off
cd /d D:\Home\Folder
echo %HOMEDRIVE%
pause
```

I get **H:** as the output. But ideally it should be **D:**. Why is it so?

Answer (score 3):

You are issuing 2 different commands and expect the same result.

you do not need to enter the first and the 2nd statement still will be H:.

This is because *%HOMEDRIVE%* is determined at login. It can be set by the domain controller or it can be a local setting.

If you want to return the current folder, just type the command `cd` or `echo %CD%`

If you want to change *%HOMEDRIVE%* to something else, for example, the current folder, use `SET HOMEDRIVE=%CD%` or directly: `SET HOMEDRIVE=D:\Home\Folder`

Keep in mind that setting *%HOMEDRIVE%* may have unexpected results if programs expect *%HOMEDRIVE%* to be H:.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to determine the current drive, you can temporarily go to the root, store the current directory, and go back, like this:

```
pushd \
set MYDRIVE=%CD%
popd
```

The `MYDRIVE` variable will have a slash at the end of it (while `HOMEDRIVE` doesn't), but Windows ignores extra slashes in paths, so even if you wind up trying to access something like `D:\\some\path`, it will still work fine.